# Parameter.Addwith not replacing

Tags: c#, mysql

The command is not replacing the value from idagent with @idagent from the mysql query. Any ideea why ? Im trying to get the id from a .txt file (and its working because i place the values the exe gets in another .txt and they show right) and use them as id for the mysql command.

edit : actually, i think the parameter is replace but the table contains no data. When i try to ouput the name variable in my result.txt it shows blank.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.xml;
using System.IO;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace PdfGenerator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillForm();
            ListFieldNames();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// List all of the form fields into a textbox.  The
        /// form fields identified can be used to map each of the
        /// fields in a PDF.
        /// </summary>
        public void ListFieldNames()
        {
            string pdfTemplate = @"C:\xampp\htdocs\site\pdfgen\PdfGenerator\form.pdf";

            // title the form
            this.Text += " - " + pdfTemplate;

            // create a new PDF reader based on the PDF template document
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);

            // create and populate a string builder with each of the 
            // field names available in the subject PDF
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
            {
              sb.Append(de.Key.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            // Write the string builder's content to the form's textbox
            textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
            textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
        }

        public void FillForm()
        {
            string idagent = null;
            string idfirma = null;
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\xampp\htdocs\site\var.txt");
                idfirma = lines[0];
                idagent = lines[1];

            using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; User Id = root; password = ; database = documente;"))
            {

                connection.Open();

                string agenti = "SELECT * FROM `agenti` WHERE `ID`=@idagent";
                string nume = null;
                string telefon = null;
                string sigiliu = null;
                string legitimatie = null;
                string prefix = null;

                using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(agenti, connection))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@idagent", idagent));
                    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\xampp\htdocs\site\result.txt");
                    file.WriteLine(idfirma);
                    file.WriteLine(idagent);
                    file.WriteLine(cmd);

                    file.Close();
                    MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(rdr);

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        nume = row["Nume Agent"].ToString();
                        telefon = row["Telefon"].ToString();
                        sigiliu = row["Sigiliu"].ToString();
                        legitimatie = row["Legitimatie"].ToString();
                        prefix = row["Prefix"].ToString();

                    }

                    string pdfTemplate = @"C:\xampp\htdocs\site\pdfgen\PdfGenerator\form.pdf";
                    string newFile = @"C:\xampp\htdocs\site\pdfgen\PdfGenerator\completed_form.pdf";

                    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
                    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(
                                newFile, FileMode.Create));

                    AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

                    // set form pdfFormFields

                    // The first worksheet and W-4 form

                    pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].numeagent[0]", nume);
                    pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].nrpv[0]", prefix);
                    pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].telefonagent[0]]", telefon);

                    // flatten the form to remove editting options, set it to false
                    // to leave the form open to subsequent manual edits
                    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;

                    // close the pdf
                    pdfStamper.Close();
                    Application.Exit();

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding parameters this way: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@idagent", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idagent;`?

Comment: @Nino i think there is something wrong with my table because i tryied to add file.Writeline in for each and they show up nothing. Any ideea why ? I think the command dose the replacement but becuase the datatable is empty i cant print anything on my pdf file. In the .txt file its just dosnt write anything.